# IPSec encryption fails to happen for IP traffic triggered using Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, ipsec

With IPSEC SP/SA configured using ipxfrm/strongswan ,SCAPY IP packets are not getting IPSec encrypted.
With same configuration (on same setup) ICMP packets sent via ping are getting IPSec encrypted

Note: Non-IPSec IP traffic is sent from scapy and i am expecting IPSec encrytion should happen by virtue of software enabled IPSec
Eventhough ICMP Packets(Scapy Vs Non-Scapy) are getting exactly matched  but it looks like IPSEC software is getting bypassed for SCAPY driven traffic resulting in IPSec encryption not happening.
Even tried with TCP and UDP IP Traffic but same issue persists.
How I can get IPSec working while using scapy as a traffic generator?

Comment: Looking forward to have some suggestions on above mentioned query .Kindly help.